# Google Sheets Charting with complex grouping

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working in a Google Sheet with data being pulled in from NPM via an Google App Script.  I'm iterating over the time periods that I'm trying to pull data for and grabbing the Download count. I'm trying to create a chart that shows the quantity of `Downloads` on the `x axis` and the `End Date` on the `y-axis` with a line for each `Package` and a legend showing the package name.  I've tried multiple types of charts as well as what feels like every combination of Series and X-axis but nothing comes out looking lime I want.

The image below the dataset is as close to what I'm looking for as I have gotten. The End Date is set as the X-axis, Downloads is set as the series, Row 1 as headers is checked, as is Use Column C as labels.

| Package | Start Date | End Date | Downloads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| my-package | 2019-12-30 | 2020-01-05 | 92834 |
| my-package | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-12 | 168066 |
| my-package | 2020-01-13 | 2020-01-19 | 184788 |
| another-package | 2019-12-30 | 2020-01-05 | 92834 |
| another-package | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-12 | 168066 |
| another-package | 2020-01-13 | 2020-01-19 | 184788 |

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of digging and attempts using Query and other stuff. I was able to get the data restructured nicely with a Pivot Table which had columns of the dates and rows of the packages. After that I was able to create a chart with the Package on the x axis and a series for the values of the packages. The dates showed up as the y axis.

[image]